# MVC API2 ActionFilterAttribute not called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I am struggeling with this peace of code:

```
public class MultiDatabaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I want to execute the OnActionExecuting on certain ActionResults in my API. This is a method in my API:

```
[MultiDatabase]
public Website Get(int id)
{
    return _websites.Get(id);
}
```

It does not work. Whatever I try, the method attribute is not called. According to the website http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/ this should work.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510362/custom-asp-net-mvc-actionfilterattribute-hooks-never-get-called) I had to add the attribute to the Global.asax. Did not help too.

Who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: What is `Website` here? Is this really an action method in a controller?

Comment: It is an object that is being returned. The other end will retrieve it as JSON. It is a method in an ApiController.

Comment: Which version of `ActionFilterAttribute` are you inheriting from here? Be aware that MVC and WebAPI have different versions.

Comment: Assembly System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35... Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting your attribute from the wrong base class. MVC and WebAPI have different objects (at least until ASP.Net Core has since merged them into one). Make sure you have the correct import in your attribute:

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
```

Or use the full namespace:

```
public class MultiDatabaseAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works! (Can't except the anwser now, I have to wait).

Off topic: Can I register the attribute so it will always be used when an action is being called without putting this attribute on 100 actions?

Comment: In your `WebApiConfig.cs`, add this line: `config.Filters.Add(new MultiDatabaseAttribute());`

Comment: Ugh, I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks again!